# Backing up files

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup

I'm looking for a method to do incremental file backups. I've found `rdiff-backup` and had a question about it: is it possible todo something along the lines of `backup to 25 feb 2012`. I know you can specify it like this: `rdiff-backup -r 10D host.net::/remote-dir/file /tmp/file` which will restore to 10 days ago, but `10 days ago` is relative, and I want to restore to a specific date. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/examples.html

> But the main advantage of rdiff-backup is that it keeps version
>   history. This command restores host.net::/remote-dir/file as it was 10
>   days ago into a new location /tmp/file.
>
> ```
> rdiff-backup -r 10D host.net::/remote-dir/file /tmp/file
> ```
>
> **> Other acceptable time strings include 5m4s (5 minutes and 4 seconds)
>   and 2002-03-05 (March 5th, 2002). For more information, see the TIME
>   FORMATS section of the manual page.**

Comment: Ouch. How could I even miss that. Thanks very much for pointing that out.

Comment: Happens to us all :P